# For loop not working in python shell while inputting data in sqlite Db

Tags: python, django, pandas, sqlite, django-models

For loop not working to input data from a python df column to a django model, i have used similar techniques in the past but this time the loop only iterates once, i tried checking the colist and it prints list of cos perfectly, doesnt seem to work inside the loop. Help would be much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from Main.models import ServiceCos
df = pd.read_csv('Assets/SERVICESdf.csv')
colist = df['Company Name']
cos_list = df['Symbol']
for c in colist:
    s = ServiceCos(company_N_ser=c) #company_N_ser is the field name
    s.save()
```

Comment: I think what it is doing is iterating over the loop and saving only the final value for some reason.

Comment: The same loop workred in postgresql.